# Change the size of an element using the mouse

Tags: selenium, webdriver

How to change the size of an element with the mouse using Selenium Webdriver?

```
actions = new Actions(webDriver);
IWebElement sourceelement = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"resizable\"]/div[3]"));
actions.ClickAndHold(sourceelement).MoveByOffset(400, 400).Release();
actions.Perform();
```

Above is the code I have written. Could someone help with this?